# Conversion between aws sqs fifo queue and standard queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

For moving from standard to fifo, I found the answer here: [aws sqs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html#FIFO-queues-moving). But what about converting a fifo queue to standard queue.

Is it possible ? If yes, what is the best way to do it. 
Assume that the queue to be converted contains lots of messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t just change the type of an existing queue from FIFO to standard, but here are two ways you can go about switching your application from a FIFO to a standard queue.

**Method 1**

1. Create a standard queue
2. Set your application to poll the FIFO and standard queues
3. Start publishing to the standard queue
4. Wait until the FIFO queue is empty
5. Remove the FIFO queue

**Method 2**

1. Create a standard queue
2. Set up your application to poll the standard queue
3. Set up a lambda function to transfer all messages from the FIFO queue to the standard queue
4. Start publishing to the standard queue
5. Once the FIFO queue is empty, delete it and the lambda function.